# 500 error server at upload theme on wordpress on bluehosting

Tags: wordpress, upload

I buy theme from themeforest and i try to upload theme but this error appear

> '500 Server Error
>
> A misconfiguration on the server caused a hiccup. Check the server
>   logs, fix the problem, then try again.'

how I can solve this error ....?

Comment: The error states "Check the server logs", did you?

Comment: how i check about that..?

Comment: A 500 Server Error just tell you "something went wrong", so there is nothing at all to go on. The issue could literally be anywhere. As @Junaid and the *error message itself* said, you need to check the server logs. If you can't figure it out then, come back and update your question with specific details

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you exceeded upload limit when uploading a theme.

[Here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/is-the-wordpress-upload-limit-giving-you-trouble-heres-how-to-change-it) is an article on how to increase it.

Basically, open *php.ini*, then find `upload_max_filesize` option and increase that limit, to something like:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```